# Pegar o valor do atributo de uma imagem e mostrá-lo abaixo

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-data

Tenho este código:

```
<script>
$(function(){
  $(".flipster").flipster({style: 'carousel', enableTouch: true, start: 0,
    onItemSwitch: function(){
      var nomeAlbum = $(this).attr("data-title");
      console.log(nomeAlbum);
    }
  }); 
});
</script>
```

A função `onItemSwitch()` me permite fazer qualquer coisa quando a imagem for trocada.
O problema é que eu estou tentando pegar o `data-titulo` de cada uma das imagens, e colocá-lo abaixo da foto do álbum.

**HTML**

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <img src="img/californication.jpg" data-title="Californication" class="imgCarousel"/>
    <p class="mostra-titulo"></p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="img/greatest-hits.jpg" data-title="Greatest Hits" class="imgCarousel" />
    <p class="mostra-titulo"></p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="img/stadium-arcadium.jpg" data-title="Stadium Arcadium" class="imgCarousel" />
    <p class="mostra-titulo"></p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="img/the-uplift-mofo-party-plan.jpg" data-title="The Upflit Mofo Party Plan" class="imgCarousel"/>
    <p class="mostra-titulo"></p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

<sup>[Aqui está o repositório do plugin](https://github.com/drien/jquery-flipster), caso ajude em algo.</sup>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tente assim:

```
// iterar todos os li
$('li').each(function() {

    // fazer cache do objecto para evitar funções a mais a correr 
    // como o @Zuul referiu nos comentários
    var $this = $(this); 

    // dentro de cada li, procurar o elemento img e
    // capturar o titulo unsando o método data() do jQuery
    var titulo = $this.find('img').data('title'); 

    // procurar elementos com a classe 'mostra-titulo' e inserir o titulo no seu HTML
    $this.find('.mostra-titulo').html(titulo); 
});
```

### [Exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/ESGbh/1/)

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente Sergio!! Muito obrigado! :D

Comment: @LuanDavi, de nada. Bom que pude ajudar.